# How do I make a textbox visible and hidden with a checkbox?

Tags: c#, wpf

So I am trying to make my textbox invisible when a checkbox is not checked. Everything works fine untill I check the box and then uncheck it again. The textbox will stay visible.

```
private void chbon_Checked_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (cchbon.IsChecked == true)
        {

            txtshow.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        }
        if (chbon.IsChecked == false)
        {
            txtshow.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        }
    }
```

This is the XAML for the Checkbox:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="chbon" Content="On" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="175,84,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="chbon_Checked_1"/>
<TextBox x:Name="txtshow" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="272,82,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="29" Visibility="Hidden"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event `Checked` does not fire when uncheck happens.
The event `Unchecked` is for that purpose.

```
... Checked="chbon_Checked" Unchecked="chbon_Unchecked"/>
```

and no need to monitor `cchbon.IsChecked` in code behind:

```
private void chbon_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        txtshow.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
}
private void chbon_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        txtshow.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

Alternatively, you can do it via binding and a converter:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis"/>
</Window.Resources>

...

<CheckBox x:Name="chbon"/>
<TextBox x:Name="txtshow" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=chbon, Path=IsChecked, 
         Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}, FallbackValue=Hidden}"/>
```

*Note that,
Once you managed this approach you may want to implement a custom converter since the built-in `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` returns `Visible`/`Collapsed` for `True`/`False` input (and not `Visible`/`Hidden`)*

Comment: BooleanToVisibilityConverter returns either Visible, or Collapsed, and that is not what original code does: Hidden is different from Collapsed

Answer (score 2):

The Checked event handler will only hit when you check the checkbox, not uncheck it. You can also use the Unchecked handler in your XAML that would make the textbox hidden.

```
private void chbon_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     txtshow.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
}

private void chbon_Checked_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     txtshow.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

when CheckBox goes to unchecked state, `Unchecked` event fires (simmetric to `Checked`). Add event handler to both of them.

```
<CheckBox x:Name="chbon" 
    Content="On" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Margin="175,84,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Checked="chbon_Checked_1"
    Unhecked="chbon_Checked_1"/>
```

```
private void chbon_Checked_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     txtshow.Visibility = cchbon.IsChecked ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

It is common to use binding to boolean property to set Visibility of some element. There is a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` in .NET, which returns `Visible` for `true`, and `Collapsed` for `false`. `Collapsed` is different from `Hidden`: `Hidden` element stil claims the space on the screen as if it was Visible.

There is a way to achieve everything in XAML using a Trigger:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="chbon" Content="On" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="175,84,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

<TextBox x:Name="txtshow" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
         Height="23" Width="29" Margin="272,82,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap">    
    <TextBox.Style>        
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">            
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=chbon}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>            
        </Style>        
    </TextBox.Style>   
<TextBox/>
```