# How to make less code with multiple checkboxes that call the same command

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, prism

I'm currently doing a program where I want to have multiple checkboxes and multiple buttons where each button is bound to one checkbox. When the checkbox is enabled, it should hide the specific button.

For the moment I can do this for one button:

```
<CheckBox Name="cbxIsClosableForUser"
     DataContext="{StaticResource GeneralVM}"
     Command="{Binding BtnToggleLblVisibilityDelegateCommand, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
     CommandParameter="{Binding LblVisibilityCloseButton}"
     Content="{m:Translate ClosingAvailableForUser}" 
     Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
     Margin="6,0,0,0"
     HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

On another View there's the buttons:

```
<Button DataContext="{StaticResource GeneralVM}"
     Visibility="{Binding LblVisibilityCloseButton, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
     Style="{StaticResource NewButtonStyle}" 
     Grid.Column="3"
     Grid.Row="3"
     PreviewMouseDown="ImQuit_PreviewMouseDown"
     HorizontalAlignment="Right"
     VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
     <Image Name="imQuit"
          Source="/CWI;component/Images/quit.png" 
     Stretch="None"/>
</Button>
```

Here's the code in the ViewModel:

```
    public Visibility LblVisibilityCloseButton
    {
        get => _LblVisibilityCloseButton;
        set
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LblVisibilityCloseButton)); 
            _LblVisibilityCloseButton = value;
        }
    }
    private Visibility _LblVisibilityCloseButton; 

    public GeneralViewModel()
    {
        LblVisibilityCloseButton = Visibility.Visible; 
        BtnToggleLblVisibilityDelegateCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(ToggleVisibility); 
    }

    public DelegateCommand<object> BtnToggleLblVisibilityDelegateCommand { get; set; } 

    private void ToggleVisibility(object obj)
    {

        if (LblVisibilityCloseButton == Visibility.Visible)
        {
            LblVisibilityCloseButton = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
        else
        {
            LblVisibilityCloseButton = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
```

Now the thing is that this checkbox works perfect. But I want multiple other checkboxes calling the same command without repeating myself and put 5 other if statements for 5 additionnal buttons.

Edit: I'm using MVVM, I don't want code behind stuff for every single checkbox.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a textbox visible and hidden with a checkbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51159920/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-visible-and-hidden-with-a-checkbox)

Comment: No it's not. I'm using commands, I don't want any code behind to handle all the stuff. And the problem isn't at all around visiblity or not, it's about making code so I don't repeat myself. All the code above works fine.

Comment: I think that the idea here is to have multiple checkboxes, calling a same command to change the different button visibilities in the view model, in order to diminish the number of commands/functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget the viewmodel way of doing this and use pure xaml solution.

```
<CheckBox Name="cbxIsClosableForUser"/>
<Button Visibility="{Binding ElementName=cbxIsClosableForUser, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

All you need to do is then to write your BooleanToVisibilityConverter, which implements the [IValueConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter?view=netframework-4.7.2) interface, load that as app resources with specific name as "BooleanToVisibilityConverter" or what ever you want and you are good to go.

If they are not in the same view, but they do share the viewmodel, then do this

```
<CheckBox Name="cbxIsClosableForUser" IsChecked="{Binding IsClosableChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<Button Visibility="{Binding IsClosableChecked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

where IsClosableChecked is your view models boolean property, the viewmodel should implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) interface properly, and notify changes in setter of the IsClosableChecked property.

Comment: I think that the checkbox and button aren't in the same view, but maybe OP can give more infos on this ?

Comment: Well basically there's a view for all the checkboxes and a view for the buttons. These two views are bound to the same ViewModel. I should have been more precise there.

Comment: Appended my answer to contain answer to your scenario.

Comment: BooleanToVisibilityConverter returns Visible for true, and Collapsed for false. Collapsed is different from Hidden which is used in ToggleVisibility method: Hidden element stil claims the space on the screen as if it was Visible.

Comment: That is all up to the implementation of the converter does it return hidden or visible, and how the user interface should work in that the case the checkbox is checked. Better way might to just disable the button if checkbox is not checked.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set `PreviewMouseDown=` to the same method. I hope that I am not wrong, but `e` variable of type `EventArgs` can contain information about the button, that called that event.

Comment: Re-read, I'm talking about checkboxes, not buttons. And I don't want methods in code behind.

Comment: You sed there, that you want to do something after you check/ uncheck any checkbox. (basically hide button) in  a method you point to from PrewiewMouseDown. That means I does not have answer, becouse I donˇt know XAML much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RelayCommands](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/20c06b/icommand-and-relaycommand-in-wpf/). You can link all the buttons to the same Command and pass an aditional CommandParamter from your xaml file. The command parameter can be handled in your VM.

Your XAML:

```
<Button x:Name"Button1" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" ..... />
```

VM:

```
    RelayCommand _myCommand;
    public ICommand MyCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_myCommand== null)
            {
                _myCommand= new RelayCommand(param =>
                {
                    if(((Button)param).Name == "Button1"){
                          //Do what you wish to do with Button1 Click
                     }
                });
            }
            return _myCommand;
        }
    }
```

I have not run this code. But, the solution is on the similar lines. You may pass some other unique parameter to your VM, on which you can distinguish which Button has triggered this command. I am passing Button itself in my parameter. You can pass an integer etc also, using `"clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"`